# Ubuntu 22.04 - How to disable auto-resizing of adjacent windows?

Tags: 22.04, window

It seems that Ubuntu has this feature as the default, where if 2 windows are next to each other and you resize one the other automatically resizes with it:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I can see how many people would find this advantageous, but I'd prefer to turn this feature off if possible.

The only work-around I'm aware of currently is to open a 3rd window, put it on top of the window I don't want to change size, then resize the other:

[image]

But this is time consuming.

Is there a way to turn this setting off?  I'm able to use `gnome-tweaks` and `dconf-editor`.  Based on other Ask Ubuntu posts I tried this setting change:

In `dconf-editor`, `org` -> `gnome` -> `mutter` -> `edge-tiling` -> turn off

But it did not turn off this feature as I've described here.